# Append base tag to head of document

Tags: php, preg-replace, simple-html-dom, radix

I'm screen scraping using Simple HTML DOM. The problem is that I'm getting relative paths/URLs which I want to replace with absolute ones:

```
foreach($html->find('</head>') as $e) 
    echo $e->append('<base href="http://www.website.com">');
```

That doesn't work. I tried some other things from answers on StackOverflow with no luck. I can get it to work with `preg_replace` like this:

```
$curl_scraped_page = preg_replace("/<*>/i", "<head><base href='$url' />", $curl_scraped_page, 1);
```

But I really want to stick to Simple HTML DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Search head instate of /head..

```
$html->find('head', 0)->append('<base href="http://www.website.com">');
```